# How to get value from a disabled text field when the value is not present in ID or in any attribute using Java in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, disabled-input, disabled-control

I have a few disabled text field auto-populated with some values based on my previous input. I want to verify whether auto-populated values are as per my previous input. But I am unable to get the value from the text field using `.getText()` or `.getAttribute()` as the value is not present in the HTML code.

Below is the HTML code got using inspect element:

```
<span class="ProductList_Row">
<input type="text" class="ProductList_Price" style="width:97px" ***disabled*** data-validation="mandatory"> == $0
```

The text is a field is auto-populated with value "100" as per my previous input. But how can I verify whether the auto-populated value is 100 in the disabled text box?

Comment: Where can be the `auto populated values` found if `the value is not present in the html code`? To retrieve the required attribute value those values need to be present in the DOM. Then only we can use  `.getText()` or `.getAttribute()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value attribute stores the content of a tag, does not matter whether it is disabled or not. So, you can do it like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("write_element_id_here")).getAttribute("value");
```

this will return you the value of the element and then you can proceed with the rest. Hope it helps..

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 4):

In your case can help the following code:

```
value = driver.findElement(By.className("ProductList_Price")).getAttribute("value");
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes and in such cases, you can use `element.getAttribute("innerHTML")` and you can then process the output string.